# Search in deeply nested array by array of "path ids" and exchange it

Tags: javascript

I wrote this map function, that should loop a very nested array of objects and find and exchange an item. To make my life easier, I also pass a path array:  [1, 4, 7, 23] that shows in which id-s my nesting happens. The last id is the item I need to swap. Here is my function:

```
() => {
  const { id, parentPath, question } = action;
  const fullPath = parentPath.concat(id);

  const findAndReplaceInSurveyItems = (item) => {
    if (fullPath[0] === item.id) {
      // pop the value, we found a match:
      fullPath.shift();
      // but we still need to continue searching...
      if (fullPath.length) {
        return {
          ...item,
          children: item.children.map(findAndReplaceInSurveyItems)
        };
      }
      // we found our match! Exchange it to the payload :)
      return {
        ...item,
        question
      };
    }

    return item;
  };

  return {
    ...state,
    questionnaire: {
      ...state.questionnaire,
      surveyItems: state.questionnaire.surveyItems.map(findAndReplaceInSurveyItems)
    }
  };
}
```

I would love your opinion on speed and overall performance.